# How do I secure that all threads created in a function return before the very same function terminates?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

Consider the following section of a **C** function:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    thread_arg *arg = (thread_arg *) malloc(sizeof(thread_arg));
    arg->random_value = random_value;
    arg->message = &(message[i * 10]);

    if (pthread_create(NULL, NULL, thread_start, (void *) &arg)) {
        perror("pthread_create");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

In this `for` loop, I create `n` threads which all perform a common routine with different parameters. This `for` loop is part of a bigger function which returns a data structure which gets modified by all threads in parallel. Thus, it is important that this bigger function won't return before all threads are done.
I was hoping to find a simpler way then giving an individual ID to all these threads and joining afterwards with `pthread_join`.
Is there any general approach to say to a function something like "hey, don't return until all threads you've created returned"?

Comment: Yes use join on all the threads at the end. What could be more simpler?

Comment: I was hoping that there is any kind of constraint, that the main thread cannot return unless all "child" threads of this thread returned. Then, I could simply call pthread_exit() right after the for loop, but I am not sure if this works.

Comment: Threads don't form this imagined hierarchy, though. All threads are more or less equal, and are "just threads". They don't remember which function created them.

Comment: @Lavair Yes calling pthread_exit from main thread works - that the program will exit when all threads complete.

Comment: @usr are you sure about this? Because without pthread_join, i thought, the main thread would just continue and call the return statement. Does the main thread really stop its execution without any call to pthread_join? Wouldn't that be contrary to what KerrekSB just stated?

Comment: @Lavair it does not stop, you need the join.

Comment: @Lavair I don't see how it contradicts with what KerrekSB said. Without `pthread_join` calls the main thread (assuming that's the one calling this "function") would simply continue. But if it doesn't wait for the threads to complete (via pthread_join calls) or call pthread_exit then it'll exit and destroy all the threads it created.

Comment: @usr hm okay, but that's exactly what I want to avoid. The main thread shouldn't force the other threads to quit in any way (what apparently isn't even true) and shouldn't return before all threads it created exited. But the issue is solved with Fredriks statements :)

Comment: @Fredrik If main thread exits, the program dies. Any thread that's still running will die when main thread exits.

Comment: @usr oh, I think there is a misunderstanding. The main thread will only return from this specific function where a specific tasks is parallelized by those multiple threads. But this is not the end of the road. The main thread won't exit completely there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least two other ways:

1. Use pthread *barriers*. The name barrier is used in a completely different sense than you usually hear it when talking about concurrency. Here, it's a synchronization primitive that lets each of a set of threads (waiters on it) block until all of them have reached it, then unblocks them all together. You'd first initialize the barrier in some shared location with `n+1` as the count, then have both the function itself and all the `n` threads it created call `pthread_barrier_wait` before finishing. Assuming you do it this way, after returning from the wait, the `n` threads can no longer access the shared state; they need to immediately return.
2. Create the same thing (or a simplified version of it) with a condvar and mutex. Have a count, protected by a mutex, of how many of the `n` threads are still working. The function that created them can then do:

   ```
   pthread_mutex_lock(&cnt_mtx);
   while (count > 0) pthread_cond_wait(&cnt_cv, &cnt_mtx);
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&cnt_mtx);
   ```

Generally, though, I'd use `pthread_join` here. That's what it's for.